# How to use the parity parameter when pricing third-party warrants with BS?

Tags: pricing, self-study, warrant

I attempt a second basic question. Let me know if https://money.stackexchange.com/ would have been more suitable for that.

[Third-party warrants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_(finance)#Third-party_warrants) are very similar to call options. One of their main characteristics is the *parity* as defined here:

> **Parity:** this represents the number of warrants needed to exercise the right on a given underlying. A parity of 10 on a call warrant on a share means that 10 call warrants need to be exercised at expiration in order to buy 1 share at the exercise price.
>
> <sub>(from https://wholesale.banking.societegenerale.com/en/news-insights/glossary/warrants/)</sub>

**If I use the Black-Scholes formula to price a warrant, where is the *parity* supposed to appear?**

Please note in "Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives, 5th edition", John C. Hull has a section p249 about "warrants issued by a company on its own stock". I think it is a different topic, as there is no dilution in third-party issued warrants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition is we can price a third-party warrant with price $c_w$ and parity ${parity}$ by pricing the equivalent option with price $c_o = c_w\times{parity}$.

$$c_w\times{parity}=N(d_1)S-N(d_2)Ke^{-r(T-t)},$$

$d_1$ and $d_2$ calculated as usual.